# Tell if WebApp launched via URL or link on iPhone home screen

Tags: iphone, web-applications

Is there a way of telling whether my Web Application has been launched from a button on the user's iPhone home screen?  I want to display a "add this WebApp to your home screen" prompt if the user has accessed the WebApp via safari by typing in a URL.

Comment: How do you make thhe link "add this webapp to your homescreen"? Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

window.navigator.standalone

True if you have launched from the Home Screen. False if in the Safari browser.

Documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

It works with OS 2.1 and up.

Answer (score 2):

In Safari, the `scrollY` will start at a negative value if inside Safari, and at 0 if running as an application.

Likely the viewport will change as well (if it does, this is a more reliable method)

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the user opening Safari from a bookmark saved to the user's home screen, not Webkit instances in non-Safari applications

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm talking about too.

Answer (score 1):

[jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) detects this (try the demo). It's open source, so you should be able to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly there's a thing in the server log that shows what the user's previous page was.  So the only way I can think of is if the user was on a previous page display the "add" thing, and if they didn't don't